# developing/testing facebook apps while I'm not a facebook fans

Tags: facebook

My next side project is a facebook app. I spent a day on reading through the facebook documentation, and then figured out my facebook wall is almost blank. So how can I get enough sample data for developing/testing facebook apps in a quick way? Or which facebook geek has an account with tons of public data that I can test my app with? (I know I can create several test users and friend/comment on/like/... each other, but it is tedious to do this you know.)

Comment: `Like` several popular pages and they will flood your wall in a while. Creating test users violates TOS (iirc) and for this puprose there are approaches: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/introduction-to-facebook-test-users-accounts-with-php-sdk/40/

Comment: @zerkms - By "test users" in my post, I mean the "Test Users Accounts" in your suggested link. With those Test Users Accounts", you still have to create data (likes, comments, etc) for them.

Comment: And you are aware that you'll need a max. one hour to write significant data to test, right?

Answer (score 0):

Test users cannot interact with other users outside of their app, so I think what you're thinking there doesn't work. Additionally, it's against Facebook TOS to log into another user's account and I'm not aware of any public data sources. Regarding finding a bunch of Facebook pages, [check out the Facebook page browser](http://www.facebook.com/pages/browser.php), which allows easy liking and management and should fill up your feed in no time.